# Can code injection be done using eval in this code?

Tags: bash, code-injection, compgen

This is my first time using bash and I know that eval have some risks when using it. Can you do a code injection to this ? For example I want to run ls command and see the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[*] Please enter the name:"
echo -n "> "
read NAME
echo "[*] Please enter the value:"
echo -n "> "
read VALUE
declare CONFIG_$NAME=$VALUE
for VARIABLE in $(compgen -v CONFIG_)
do
   echo "- $VARIABLE: $(eval echo \$$VARIABLE)"
done
```

Comment: If the expansion of `$VARIABLE` contains `;ls` it will be injected.

Comment: However, it's possible that `compgen` adds extra quotes that might prevent that.

Comment: I tried setting $VARIABLE to be ;ls but it would be a not valid identifier and won't work.

Answer (score 3):

If `$VARIABLE` contains `;` the command after it will be executed

```
VARIABLE=';ls'
echo "- $VARIABLE: $(eval echo \$$VARIABLE)"
```

The command executed by `eval` is

```
echo $;ls
```

Since `$` isn't followed by an identifier, it's simply echoed literally. Then `ls` is executed.

You could also put a valid identifier at the beginning:

```
foo=123
VARIABLE="foo;ls"
```

This will execute

```
echo $foo;ls
```

so it will echo `123` then the output of `ls`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer it helped a lot ! Is it possible to have VARIABLE be ;ls ? because when I try it I get 'not a valid identifier' error.

Comment: I executed the code I showed on a Mac. Maybe later versions of bash don't allow it.

Comment: I just tried it on Linux running bash 5.0.3 and it worked as well.

Comment: @Barmar In the script, `VARIABLE` is set from the output of `compgen -v CONFIG_` -- is there a way to get *that* to output something containing ";ls"?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this particular use of `eval` is safe as it only ever operates on valid identifiers, or alternatively, requires a level of control over the execution that makes the exploit itself moot.

As an attacker, I would have ignored the `eval` and used one of the other entry points instead, e.g.

```
$ ./myscript
[*] Please enter the name:
> [`date>&2`]
[*] Please enter the value:
> foo
Thu 05 Nov 2020 04:00:37 PM PST
- CONFIG_: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to using `eval` with Bash 3.2+, you can use indirect variable reference `${!varname}`

```sh
for variable in $(compgen -v CONFIG_)
do
   echo "- $variable: ${!variable}"
done
```

With Bash version 4.2+ you can do the same with **nameref** variables `declare -n var`:

```sh
for variable in $(compgen -v CONFIG_)
do
  declare -n value=$variable
  echo "- $variable: $value"
done
```

Comment: Indirect variable expansion was  introduced in Bash 2.0 (1996).  See [Bash-2.0 release available for FTP](https://groups.google.com/g/gnu.bash.bug/c/WE1Fa--vKw0/m/l9S7xZFP44AJ).